# Write a function that takes (x, y) and return x to the power of y WITHOUT Loops

Tags: popularity-contest, math, restricted-source

This is a really neat short challenge.

Write a function or a procedure that takes two parameters, `x` and `y` and returns the result of `xy` WITHOUT using loops, or built in power functions.

**The winner is the most creative solution, and will be chosen based on the highest number of votes after 3 days.**

Comment: What sort of challenge is this?

Comment: @VisioN A think-out-of-the-box challenge, I suppose

Comment: How about `exp(log(x)*y)`?

Comment: I see you haven't read the cube root question. Is exp allowed? if so the answer is exp(ln(x)*y). Depending on the language you may have to protect for negative and zero x, but there are some that can handle it. I recommend you exclude exp specifically.

Comment: Even though the tag has been changed this question still has no objective winning criterion. [code-challenge] questions should have a method for scoring individual answers.

Comment: @nitro2k01, please note Gareth's point. Code challenge needs a winning criterion specified.

Comment: Is an answer for integers only acceptable? Since these are the first replies.

Comment: @steveverrill Does it have to have scoring, or just a winning criterion? The winning criterion would be to make a function that returns x to the power of y. I didn't expect the influx of answers using recursion as a way of getting around the need for loops. If that hole in the rules wasn't there, it would indeed be more of a challenge. I'm feeling that all of the answers so far are violating the spirit of the rules because of this.

Comment: @nitro2k01 See the code challenge page. "A code challenge is a competition...with an objective winning criterion not covered by other scoring tags." That means you have to define it. And it can't be yes/no, because that is "first valid answer accepted" which discourages competition. Some other tags, such as code golf (shortest code) or popularity contest (most votes) have an implied objective (and numeric) winning criterion (in addition to "complies with requirements.") Anyway, the OP has fixed it now. Spirit of rules can be decided by vote. A good non-recursive answer will get massive upvotes

Comment: Looks like the answers so far either use recursion or lists of repeated 'x's. I'm wracking my brains trying to think of another way (particularly something that allows a non-integer y).

Comment: @BenM mine is different, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately the prohibition on loops rules out fun mathematical solutions like Taylor expansion.

Comment: No loops? Sounds like a **loop**hole (no pun intended) would be using recursion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### APL (7)

```
{×/⍵/⍺}
```

Left argument is base, right argument is exponent, e.g.:

```
     5 {×/⍵/⍺} 6
15625
```

Explanation:

- `⍵/⍺` replicates `⍺` `⍵` times, e.g. `5 {⍵/⍺} 6` -> `5 5 5 5 5 5`
- `×/` takes the product, e.g. `×/5 5 5 5 5 5` -> `5×5×5×5×5×5` -> `15625`

Comment: Hm.. This can be written in 5 characters in J, exactly the same method. `*/@$~`

Comment: @Sieg 4 even, if you allow exponent on the left, base on the right.

Comment: I had the flip adverb because I thought it's not allowed.

Comment: @Seeq 4 in [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM): `×/⍴⍨`

Answer (score 27):

## C#: Floating point exponents

OK, this solution is quite fragile. You can easily break it by throwing ridiculously huge numbers like 6 at it. But it works beautifully for things like `DoublePower(1.5, 3.4)`, and doesn't use recursion!

```
    static double IntPower(double x, int y)
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(x, y).Aggregate((product, next) => product * next);
    }

    static double Factorial(int x)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, x).Aggregate<int, double>(1.0, (factorial, next) => factorial * next);
    }

    static double Exp(double x)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 100).
            Aggregate<int, double>(1.0, (sum, next) => sum + IntPower(x, next) / Factorial(next));
    }

    static double Log(double x)
    {
        if (x > -1.0 && x < 1.0)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 100).
                Aggregate<int, double>(0.0, (sum, next) =>
                    sum + ((next % 2 == 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0) / next * IntPower(x - 1.0, next)));
        }
        else
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 100).
                Aggregate<int, double>(0.0, (sum, next) =>
                    sum + 1.0 / next * IntPower((x - 1) / x, next));
        }
    } 

    static double DoublePower(double x, double y)
    {
        return Exp(y * Log(x));
    }
```

Comment: "ridiculously huge numbers like 6"  I enjoyed that.

Comment: Surely use of Enumerable functions is relying on looping that was forbidden in the question or is it ok because the loop is inside framework methods?

Answer (score 15):

## C++

How about some template meta programming? It bends what little rules there were, but it's worth a shot:

```
#include <iostream>


template <int pow>
class tmp_pow {
public:
    constexpr tmp_pow(float base) :
        value(base * tmp_pow<pow-1>(base).value)
    {
    }
    const float value;
};

template <>
class tmp_pow<0> {
public:
    constexpr tmp_pow(float base) :
        value(1)
    {
    }
    const float value;
};

int main(void)
{
    tmp_pow<5> power_thirst(2.0f);
    std::cout << power_thirst.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but this isn't a function, is a compile-time value, isn't it? :O

Comment: Well, a constructor is a function, and template parameters are almost like function arguments... right? =)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Yeah... that's why I admitted to some rule bending. I thought I was going to submit something besides tail-recursion, but I just submitted compile time tail recursion, haha. Close enough though, right?

Comment: @astephens4 close enough, I love it :3

Answer (score 15):

### Python

```
def power(x,y):
    return eval(((str(x)+"*")*y)[:-1])
```

Doesn't work for noninteger powers.

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: Why are you adding a separator *without* using `join`? `eval('*'.join([str(x)] * y))`.

Comment: Was this code-trolling?

Comment: Would like to also note that python has the `**` operator, so you could've eval()d that.

Comment: @Riking: that'd be an inbuilt, though.

Comment: upvote for `[:-1]`

Answer (score 10):

## Python

If `y` is a positive integer

```
def P(x,y):
    return reduce(lambda a,b:a*b,[x]*y)
```

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell - 25 chars

```
f _ 0=1
f x y=x*f x (y-1)
```

Following Marinus' APL version:

```
f x y = product $ take y $ repeat x
```

With mniip's comment and whitespace removed, 27 chars:

```
f x y=product$replicate y x
```

Comment: use `replicate y x` instead of `take y $ repeat x`

Comment: I was convinced that you could save characters by writing your second function pointfree. As it turns out `f=(product.).flip replicate` is exactly the same number of chars.

Comment: @mniip It doesn't matter, this isn't code golf.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31

```js
// Testable in Firefox 28
f=(x,y)=>eval('x*'.repeat(y)+1)
```

**Usage:**

```js
> f(2, 0)
1
> f(2, 16)
65536
```

**Explanation:**

The above function builds an expression which multiply `x` `y` times then evaluates it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised to see that nobody wrote a solution with the Y Combinator, yet... thus:

## Python2

```
Y = lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda v: y(y)(v)))
pow = Y(lambda r: lambda (n,c): 1 if not c else n*r((n, c-1)))
```

No loops, No vector/list operations and No (explicit) recursion!

```
>>> pow((2,0))
1
>>> pow((2,3))
8
>>> pow((3,3))
27
```

Comment: Uh, I've just seen right now KChaloux's Haskell solution that uses `fix`, upvoting him...

Answer (score 5):

## C# : 45

Works for integers only:

```
int P(int x,int y){return y==1?x:x*P(x,y-1);}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-)  I think you could save a few bytes by writing `return --y?x:x*P(x,y);` instead

Comment: But this isn't [tag:code-golf]...

Comment: @oberon winning criteria was not clear when this was posted. Things have moved on.

Comment: @steveverrill Sorry.

Comment: Also in C# --y would be an int which is not the same as a bool like in other languages.

Answer (score 5):

## bash & sed

No numbers, no loops, just an embarrasingly dangerous glob abuse. Preferably run in an empty directory to be safe. Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f xxxxx*
eval touch $(printf xxxxx%$2s | sed "s/ /{1..$1}/g")
ls xxxxx* | wc -l
rm -f xxxxx*
```

Comment: "Preferably run in an empty directory to be safe." :D

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript

```
function f(x,y){return ("1"+Array(y+1)).match(/[\,1]/g).reduce(function(l,c){return l*x;});}
```

Uses regular expressions to create an array of size y+1 whose first element is 1. Then, reduce the array with multiplication to compute power. When y=0, the result is the first element of the array, which is 1.

Admittedly, my goal was i) not use recursion, ii) make it obscure.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica

```
f[x_, y_] := Root[x, 1/y]
```

Probably cheating to use the fact that x^(1/y) = y√x

Comment: Not cheating. Smart.

Comment: This is brilliant. Wish I'd thought of it for my R post.

Answer (score 4):

## Golfscript, 8 characters (including I/O)

```
~])*{*}*
```

Explanation:

TLDR: another "product of repeated array" solution.

The expected input is two numbers, e.g. `2 5`. The stack starts with one item, the string `"2 5"`.

```
Code     - Explanation                                             - stack
                                                                   - "2 5"
~        - pop "2 5" and eval into the integers 2 5                - 2 5        
]        - put all elements on stack into an array                 - [2 5]
)        - uncons from the right                                   - [2] 5
*        - repeat array                                            - [2 2 2 2 2]
{*}      - create a block that multiplies two elements             - [2 2 2 2 2] {*}
*        - fold the array using the block                          - 32
```

Comment: Golfscript is always the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby

```
class Symbol
  define_method(:**) {|x| eval x }
end

p(:****[$*[0]].*(:****$*[1]).*('*'))
```

Sample use:

```
$ ruby exp.rb 5 3
125
$ ruby exp.rb 0.5 3
0.125
```

This ultimately is the same as several previous answers: creates a y-length array every element of which is x, then takes the product. It's just gratuitously obfuscated to make it look like it's using the forbidden `**` operator.

Answer (score 3):

## C, exponentiation by squaring

```
int power(int a, int b){
    if (b==0) return 1;
    if (b==1) return a;
    if (b%2==0) return power (a*a,b/2);
    return a*power(a*a,(b-1)/2);
}
```

golfed version in **46 bytes** (thanks ugoren!)

```
p(a,b){return b<2?b?a:1:p(a*a,b/2)*(b&1?a:1);}
```

should be faster than all the other recursive answers so far o.O

slightly slower version in **45 bytes**

```
p(a,b){return b<2?b?a:1:p(a*a,b/2)*p(a,b&1);}
```

Comment: For odd `b`, `~-b/2 == b/2`.

Comment: @ugoren oh sure, you're right

Comment: This is a popular interview question :) "How can you write `pow(n, x)` better than O(n)?"

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript

```javascript
function f(x,y){return y--?x*f(x,y):1;}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell - 55

```
pow x y=fix(\r a i->if i>=y then a else r(a*x)(i+1))1 0
```

There's already a shorter Haskell entry, but I thought it would be interesting to write one that takes advantage of the `fix` function, as defined in `Data.Function`. Used as follows (in the Repl for the sake of ease):

```
ghci> let pow x y=fix(\r a i->if i>=y then a else r(a*x)(i+1))1 0
ghci> pow 5 3
125
```

Answer (score 2):

## Q

9 chars. Generates array with `y` instances of `x` and takes the product.

```
{prd y#x}
```

Can explicitly cast to float for larger range given int/long x:

```
{prd y#9h$x}
```

Comment: Matching Golfscript in length is a feat to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Similar logic as many others, in PHP:

```
<?=array_product(array_fill(0,$argv[2],$argv[1]));
```

Run it with `php file.php 5 3` to get 5^3

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how many upvotes I can expect for this, but I found it somewhat peculiar that I *actually* had to write that very function today. And I'm *pretty sure* this is the first time any .SE site sees [this language](http://www.abs-models.org/) (website doesn't seem very helpful atm).

## ABS

```java
def Rat pow(Rat x, Int y) =
    if y < 0 then
        1 / pow(x, -y)
    else case y {
        0 => 1;
        _ => x * pow(x, y-1);
    };
```

Works for negative exponents and rational bases.

I highlighted it in Java syntax, because that's what I'm currently doing when I'm working with this language. Looks alright.

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal

The challenge did not specify the type or range of x and y, therefore I figure the following Pascal function follows all the given rules:

```
{ data type for a single bit: can only be 0 or 1 }
type
  bit = 0..1;

{ calculate the power of two bits, using the convention that 0^0 = 1 }
function bitpower(bit x, bit y): bit;
  begin
    if y = 0
      then bitpower := 1
      else bitpower := x
  end;
```

No loop, no built-in power or exponentiation function, not even recursion or arithmetics!

Answer (score 2):

### J - 5 or 4 bytes

Exactly the same as [marinus' APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22986/20356).

For `x^y`:

```
*/@$~
```

For `y^x`:

```
*/@$
```

For example:

```
   5 */@$~ 6
15625
   6 */@$ 5
15625
```

`x $~ y` creates a list of `x` repeated `y` times (same as `y $ x`

`*/ x` is the product function, `*/ 1 2 3` -> `1 * 2 * 3`

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```python
from math import sqrt

def pow(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    elif y >= 1:
        return x * pow(x, y - 1)
    elif y > 0:
        y *= 2
        if y >= 1:
            return sqrt(x) * sqrt(pow(x, y % 1))
        else:
            return sqrt(pow(x, y % 1))
    else:
        return 1.0 / pow(x, -y)
```

Comment: ** is built-in operator imo.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea True, editing.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea operator `=/=` function

Comment: @VisioN true, but the idea was about built-ins. I don't think the OP knows about all these built-in operators ...

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

With tail recursion, works if `y` is a positive integer

```
function P(x,y,z){z=z||1;return y?P(x,y-1,x*z):z}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash

Everyone knows `bash` can do whizzy map-reduce type stuff ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$1
reduce () {
    ((a*=$x))
}
a=1
mapfile -n$2 -c1 -Creduce < <(yes)
echo $a
```

---

If thats too trolly for you then there's this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(( $( yes $1 | head -n$2 | paste -s -d'*' ) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica

This works for integers.

```
f[x_, y_] := Times@@Table[x, {y}]
```

**Example**

```
f[5,3]
```

> 125

---

**How it works**

`Table` makes a list of `y` `x`'s.  `Times` takes the product of all of them.`

---

**Another way to achieve the same end**:

```
#~Product~{i,1,#2}&
```

**Example**

```
#~Product~{i, 1, #2} & @@ {5, 3}
```

> 125

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript  <s>formerly 44</s>   , now 41

```
f=(x,y)=>y?eval(Array(y).join(x+"*")+x):1

TESTING:
alert(f(5,3))
OUTPUT (alert): 125
alert(f(6,3))
OUTPUT (alert): 216
alert(f(8,0))
OUTPUT (alert): 1
```

Changes, altered logic to allow reversed execution, thus removing 3 characters...

Only works for positive integers

Comment: `f(2,0)` returns `2` instead of `1`

Comment: A more ES6 solution: `f=(x,y)=>{a=1;[x for (i of Array(y))].map(z=>a*=z);return a}`

Comment: @Florent Corrected for x^0... And your ES6 solution unfortunately is using a `for` loop :/

Comment: Well, it’s a list comprehension. Is it closer to a loop than `map`?

Comment: I'm not using `for` nor am I using `while`, @minitech, plain and simple...

Comment: I didn’t say you were. What I said was that the `for` in Florent’s ES6 isn’t a `for` loop – it’s a list comprehension. I consider that a lot closer to `map` than a typical `for`.

Comment: Fair enough @minitech. :) +1 to you.

Comment: @WallyWest How about: `f=(x,y)=>y&&(Array(y).join(x+",")+x).split(",").reduce((a,b)=>a*b,1)`?

Comment: @WallyWest Your code doesn't work with `0` for `y`.

Comment: @toothbrush Give me a few moments, I had a flash of inspiration earlier this morning...

Answer (score 1):

### Scala - 47

```
def p(x:Int,y:Int)=(1 to y).fold(1)((a,b)=>a*x)
```

Not dissimilar to the other functional versions that use a variant of `repeat` or `replicate`, with the exception that it takes a *lot* of characters to repeat something in Scala (Stream.continually(x).take(y)).

This version iterates over the range of 1..y, but completely throws out the captured value at each step, instead multiplying the accumulator by the base value 'x'. I was originally going to use `map` to transform the range into all instances of the value x, and use the `product` function to multiply it, but this version is actually a bit shorter.

Usage

```
scala> def p(x:Int,y:Int)=(1 to y).fold(1)((a,b)=>a*x)
p: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> p(5,3)
res44: Int = 125
```

Answer (score 1):

## C

Yet another recursive exponentiation by squaring answer in C, but they do differ (this uses a shift instead of division, is slightly shorter and recurses one more time than the other):

```
e(x,y){return y?(y&1?x:1)*e(x*x,y>>1):1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

### perl

Here's a tail recursive perl entry. Usage is echo $X,$Y | foo.pl:

```
($x,$y) = split/,/, <>;
sub a{$_*=$x;--$y?a():$_}
$_=1;
print a
```

Or for a more functional-type approach, how about:

```
($x,$y) = split/,/, <>;
$t=1; map { $t *= $x } (1..$y);
print $t
```

Comment: "a: stuff goto a if something" looks like a loop.

Comment: Yep, the goto version is a loop, but isn't tail recursion also essentially a loop?

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8

```java
public long power(long num, int pow) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(1, pow).reduce(1, (i, j) -> i * num);
}
```

does not work with negative powers.

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
def getRootOfY(x,y):
   return x**y 

def printAnswer():
   print "answer is ",getRootOfY(5,3)
printAnswer()

answer =125
```

I am not sure if this is against the requirements, but if not here is my attempt.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! When you do your language header you can leave out the "language=" since by custom everyone puts the language in the header so that's understood. You may indeed have run afoul of the rules here, but we'll let the voters decide. Glad to have a new member at the country club.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Batch

Like most of the other answers here, it uses recursion.

```
@echo off
set y=%2
:p
if %y%==1 (
set z=%1
goto :eof
) else (
    set/a"y-=1"
    call :p %1
    set/a"z*=%1"
    goto :eof
)
```

x^y is stored in the environment variable `z`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    int v=getpow(4,3);
    System.out.println(v);
    }
public static int getpow(int b, int v) {
     if (v == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return b * getpow(b, v - 1);
    }
}
```

Java:
I/P: 3 and 4
O/P: 64

Answer (score 1):

It's important to return a precise answer, and to support large numbers -

```
public static BigInteger power(int x, int y) {
    return (y > 0) ? power(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(x)), y)
            : BigInteger.ONE;
}

public static BigInteger power(BigInteger x, int y) {
    return (y > 0) ? power(x, y - 1).multiply(x) : BigInteger.ONE;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // From here
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two
    String result = "13,407,807,929,942,597,099,574,024,998,205,846,127,479,365,820,592,"
            + "393,377,723,561,443,721,764,030,073,546,976,801,874,298,166,903,427,690,"
            + "031,858,186,486,050,853,753,882,811,946,569,946,433,649,006,084,096";
    result = result.replace(",", "");
    System.out.println(result.equals(power(2, 512).toString()));
}
```

Of course, the output is

```
true
```

Comment: This isn't a code-trolling challenge.  You were supposed to return the value of x^y.

Comment: What do you think `2^512` is?

Comment: Oh, you overflowed the size of the `BigInteger`?

Comment: I was thinking it always returned `true`.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript/HTML, cheater's (DIY) way:

```
function (a, b) { return "" + a + "<sup>" + b + "</sup>"; }
```

example run: http://jsfiddle.net/r4LfF/1/ (click "run" if it doesn't show up automatically)
maybe it can be done better, but I don't know Javascript!..

Comment: funny solution!

Comment: "Standard loopholes are not funny anymore"

Comment: @Jacob unfortunately, I have read this long after the solution was posted.

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple recursive Python solution, works when y is non-negative integer:

```
def f(x, y):
    return 1 if y == 0 else x * f(x, y - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6 (32 bytes):

```
p=(x,y)=>y>2?p(x,--y)*x:+!y||x*x
```

Defines a function named `p` which takes `x` and `y` as parameters, and returns `x` to the power of `y`, without using any built-in functions, or loops.

Answer (score 1):

**C, 79**

This is an optimized version of the standard recursive call.  It refactors each successive call by powers of 2.  In other words if y is 2^n, it will be called n times.

```
typedef uint64_t Z;Z p(Z x,Z y){return(!y)?1:(1==y)?x:((y&1)?x:1)*p(x*x,y>>1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### R

A cheap trick for positive integer-valued `y`:

```
hacky <- function(x, y) Reduce(`*`, rep(x, y))
```

And an approximation for real-valued `y`. As far as I'm aware, `apply` is not technically implemented as a loop:

```
mathy <- function(x, y, nterms) {
  sum(sapply(seq_len(nterms), function(i) Reduce(`*`, rep(y * log(x), i)) / factorial(i))) + 1
}
```

This one computed x^y=exp(y*log(x)) by taking the Taylor expansion of the right hand side. It can also be done recursively if you're leery of `apply`:

```
recursive <- function(x, y, nterms) {
  taylor <- function(n) {
    if(n==0) z <- 1
    else z <- Reduce(`*`, rep(y * log(x), n)) / factorial(n) + taylor(n-1)
    z
  }
  taylor(nterms)
}
```

And the *coup-de-grace*:

```
goofy <- function(x, y, nterms) {
  eval(parse(text = paste(
    sprintf("Reduce(`*`, (%s * log(%s))^%i) / factorial(%i)", y, x, 0:nterms, 0:nterms),
    collapse=" + "
  )))
}
```

---

I ran some single-run benchmarks for fun. Formatting them for looking pretty here is going to be more of a pain than it's worth, but I was surprised to see that the `apply` version was actually slower than the recursive version for small numbers of terms, and that their timings converged up to the maximum number of terms (171, the largest integer that `factorial` will accept). The text-based version was slower still for small numbers of terms, but was actually twice as fast for the large number of terms. They obviously fail dramatically compared to R's built-in versions.

Interestingly, it seems like R (or the package I'm using to benchmark, `microbenchmark`) does some magic in its innards, and when I set `microbenchmark` to use more than one trial all of the times drop by several orders of magnitude. The variation follows a similar pattern, but the differences are now in nanoseconds rather than logarithms of miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
def pow (x, y):
    class Num:
        n = 1
        def __eq__ (self, v):
            Num.n *= v
            return False
    x in [Num()] * y
    return Num.n

x=2
y=3
print(pow(x, y))
```

Weirdo.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC

*For TI-83/84 calculators*

```
:Input X,Y
:Lbl 1
:Y-1->Y
:X*X->X
:If 1<Y
:Goto 1
:X
```

Displays/returns `X`

Answer (score 1):

Pascal;

```
FUNCTION pwr(base,power:REAL):REAL;    // calculates base**power for base >0.0 
BEGIN   
  IF base > 0.0 THEN pwr := EXP(power*LN(base)) ELSE HALT(1);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++

Since most answers use some language quirks to get things done, i thought about trying to spice things up using quirks of data types themselves. Following function uses integer representation of IEEE float to get a logarithm approximation.

Blazingly fast and inaccurate.

```
float fapxpow(float x, float y) {
    __int32 lx = *(__int32 *)&x;
    lx = (lx - 0x3F7A7DD3)*y + 0x3F7A7DD3;
    float xy = *(float *)&lx;
    return xy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## R

```
f=function(x,y) prod(c(rep(x,y)))
```

Not super sure about 'prod', I didn't check how it's implemented. I might just be calling a loop here.

Answer (score 0):

### F#

Since `^` and `**` were already taken and infix operators are fun, let's call it `^^`

```
let rec (^^) (x: int) y =
  let fx = float x
  match y with
  | y when y < 0 -> (x ^^ y + 1) / fx
  | 0 -> 1.0
  | y -> (x ^^ y - 1) * fx
```

`x` and `y` are integers and it returns a float, since it handles negative exponents. Call it with `x ^^ y`

Answer (score 0):

## Delphi XE3

Uses a recursive function that will keep calling itself until multiplied according to the power.

Required input like `p^o`

```
var
  p,o:integer;

  function Pwr(n,r,c:integer):integer;
  begin
    if c=o then
      Result:=r
    else
      Result:=Pwr(n,r*p,c+1);
  end;
begin
    readln(p,o);
    Writeln(Pwr(o,p,1));
    readln;
end.
```

Input: `2 5`
Output: `32`

Answer (score 0):

## C

```
int power(int x,int y)
{
if ( y!=1 )
    return (x*power(x,y-1));
}
```

What is this illegal?

Comment: what if condition not true ?? no return

Comment: @Omer the question didn't specify that the function should work for all x and y. For instance none of the functions would work for y<=0. I could add a condition to work for y==1. But I don't see any need for it currently.

Comment: @user689 My answer handles **all** valid ECMAScript numbers (whole and floating-point; negative and non-negative).

Answer (score 0):

### PHP

```
function altpow($x,$y) {
    if ( $y > 0 ) {
        return array_product(array_fill(0,$y,$x));
    } else if ( $y < 0 ) {
        return 1/array_product(array_fill(0,$y*-1,$x));
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Doesn't work with floating point exponents.

Test:

```
pow(4.33,-5) // 0.00065699266096183
altpow(4.33,-5) // 0.00065699266096183
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using C++**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float power(float x, float y) {
    if(y  == 0)
    return 1;
    if(y == 1)
    return x;

    return power(x,y-1) *x;

    }

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   cout<<power(2,3);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure

```
(defn pow [x y]
 (if (= y 0) 1  
  (reduce * x (take (- y 1) (repeat x)))))

(pow 2 2)
=> 4
```

It will not work for negative exponent.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an explanation of how it works?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to work for `2, 0`, `0, 0`, or `2, -2`.

Comment: This is a little overcomplicated. `(defn pow [x y] (if (<= y 0) 1 (reduce * (repeat y x))))` works just fine. @toothbrush It takes list of `x` repeated `y` times and returns the product (`(reduce * [1 2 3])` == `1 * 2 * 3`)

Comment: @Sieg Yes, but `x` to the power of `0` is **always** `1`.

Comment: @toothbrush That is why the if-clause is there. See, if the first argument is true (that being `(<= y 0)` which is more traditionally `y <= 0`), then it returns the second argument (that being `1`). Otherwise it returns the third argument, which is the product.

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8 lambda recursion

```
    static BinaryOperator<Integer> powerof;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    powerof = (x, y) -> {return y == 0 ? 1 : x * powerof.apply(x, y-1);};
    System.out.println(powerof.apply(5, 3));
}
```

Guess it's kind of late, but I'll post anyway to celebrate the imminent release of java 8 :)

Answer (score 0):

### Another Mathematica Solution, 33 characters

```
D[ExpIntegralEi[(1 + y) Log[x]], x, y]
```

I believe that this does not violate the rule against using "built in power functions", as while the exponential integral function implies E^t dt, it does *not* involve x^y.

This solution is unusual among those posted here in that it works for more than just positive integers, and in fact works for any complex numbers for both x and y.

Answer (score 0):

## Python

```
import math
def recurse_log(x, minimum, cur):
    val = math.log(cur, x)
    if cur == minimum:
        return (val,)
    else:
        return recurse_log(x, minimum, cur-1) + (val,)

def exp(x,y):
    crude_ans = 1<<(int(y*math.log2(x)))
    min_ans = crude_ans//2
    max_ans = crude_ans*2
    possible = list(recurse_log(x, min_ans, max_ans))
    return min_ans + min(range(len(possible)), key=lambda v: abs(possible[v]-y))
```

Works only with integers. This code finds a crude calculation of the answer using log base two and a bitshift (which serves as a base 2 exponents). This gives an answer accurate to the nearest power of two. Then, it takes the log of every integer in the possible range and sees which is closest.

It's very very slow.

Comment: Interesting idea, but **"WITHOUT Loops"** vs. `for i in range` ?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I guess list comprehensions count as loops. I changed it to use a recursive function, but that hits Python's recursion limit for large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, ES5+

This may be bending the rules a bit, due to the use of `forEach`, although it's not being used in the typical fashion.

```
function pwr(x, y){
  var array1 = [], i = 0, result = 1;
  array1.push(function(){i++; result *= x; if(i >= y) throw {};});
  array1.push(function(a){array1.forEach(a)});
  try{
    array1.forEach(array1[1]);
  }
  catch(e){
    return result;
  }
}
console.log(pwr(3,4)); //81
```

`y` must be an integer; `x` does not need to be.

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly - 3 bytes

```
x×/
```

Pretty much identical to the APL and J solutions, but as a newer language Jelly is more efficient.

`x` turns a,b into [a,a,...,a] (length b)

`×/` computes reduce(c,d-->c×d, [a,a,...,a]), to get a×a×...×a = a^b.

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 42 bytes

```fs
fun(x,y)->Seq.reduce(*)<|Seq.replicate y x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwHMT3PsVREFKxAQc3KfgMHcUhJP9goCRtPiCBvnuMOrl5091vuDsdRuk81aqTZflUhnGaaeOeVJLEjsN1/8Z1MVJEQkGunXYeGcbifub88oByeKPygzo0rd7YqC36ww1emEAK0SE@CQ3QlsQSmutbWwH77O/T/0@G@gI)