# Another Euler Brick in the Wall

Tags: code-challenge, math, fastest-code

A [Euler Brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick) is a cuboid where the length of all the edges are integers and all of the diagonals of the faces are integers as well. All sides must also be different.

[image]

Your program has to find as many different Euler Bricks where the sides are less than L within the time M (L and M will be defined later).

All of your calculated bricks have to be unique. This means that if your dimensions are the same, just in a different order, it must not be counted.

To calculate a brick means to find the lengths of the edges and the lengths of the diagonals of the faces of a valid Euler Brick.

Your bricks must also be indivisible by each other. In the same way that the Pythagorean triplet `6, 8, 10` is divisible by `3, 4, 5`, your bricks must ***not*** be divisible by each other.

To test your program, I will need to the following:

1. The language your code is written in
2. A command to run your code
3. Your code

Your score will be the average number of bricks your program calculates (running the program five times). To do this, I will run your program and end it after M minutes have elapsed. Once you have submitted your answer, I will add a comment on your answer telling what your score is. If you make an edit to your code, please notify me directly so I can find your score again.

For that reason, I need your program to print the number of bricks either at throughout the running or at the end. This can be done like so (in Python it would help if people told me how to do this in other languages for this example):

```
try:
    # Calculation goes here

except KeyboardInterrupt: # I will use Ctrl-C
    print(numberofbricks)
    exit()
```

For this challenge `L=10^30` and `M=2 minutes`. In the event of a tie, the actual time taken to calculate all of the bricks will be used. The lower time wins.

I will find your time using the script below. All programs will be tested on the same machine.

```
import time, subprocess
command = # How do you run your program?
s=time.time()
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
e=time.time()
print(e-s)
```

### Leaderboard

```
1. Peter Taylor  - 5731679685.5 bricks per minute
2. Steve Verrill - 680262303 bricks per minute
3. Beta Decay    - 0.5 bricks per minute
```

Comment: Why is there an [underhanded] category if they all get put on hold. "There are either too many possible answers..." which is kinda to key to obfuscation.

Comment: According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerBrick.html no "perfect" Euler brick with integral internal diagonal is known. If anyone comes  up with a viable method, the whole world maths community will congratulate them. Voting to reopen because I like to dream, but I would prefer a straight Euler Brick code challenge: (bricks found in a minute) / (bytes).

Comment: I have worked on this problem (not as a programming exercise), and so have a lot of other people. In fact, I'm sure that supercomputers have been put to this task. I don't understand the reopen votes unless the **perfect** requirement is removed.

Comment: @AndoDaan Good underhanded questions ask you to do one (specific) thing and pretend to do another. Questions like this here are just saying "pretend you're doing this thing, but in fact you can do *whatever you want*". That's what's too broad. In addition, as Steve and Eric point out, it is unlikely that it's even possible to write a program which does correctly compute the brick which means there are even less invalid programs.

Comment: Betadecay, now that you've removed the "perfect" requirement per @EricTressler's comment, this becomes a realistic problem, so I see no need for the underhanded. It's generally not a very well received tag. By the way,  Eric, we've had some well received questions about unproven conjectures before, such as this one:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25247/lets-take-beals-1-000-000/25556#25556

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'll have to agree with your far greater experience. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @steveverrill The problem to which you referred was worded much differently; it was asking for legitimate methods of attempting to disprove a theorem. The analogue here would be to ask for algorithms that attempt to verify the existence of a perfect Euler brick, which I would have been in favor of. A new method for a problem like this, generally running on a cluster or something, always has a chance of proving something new.

Comment: @EricTressler I think we are saying the same thing in different ways. I would like to see the underhanded tag eliminated and the question revised in line with what you say in your last comment. I think a Euler brick question is a great idea - I like the fact that although it is unlikely that anyone would find a perfect Euler brick, at least there is some output (regular Euler bricks) on the way. However I don´t want it enough to go a ahead and edit/hijack the OP's question.

Comment: The updated winning criterion is going to lead to disputes, so it isn't fit for purpose. You need to specify how duplicate bricks should be counted (probably by specifying that the edges must be sorted in ascending order) and then you need a single benchmark which you will verify for each competitor in conditions which are as similar as possible.

Comment: Okay, much better. One more thing now: isn't your challenge trivially solved by hardcoding the smallest Euler brick and spitting out 1,000,000 multiples of it?

Comment: You could probably fix that by having a scoring like "Find the most Euler bricks with side-length less than L within m minutes." Where you pick L and m such that just producing multiples of a few hardcoded Bricks will hit L way before hitting m, but such that it's unlikely that anyone can find *all* bricks less than L in the given time (and if people do, the tie-breaker is the actual time they took).

Comment: Martin's proposal is probably the best solution, because at present the obvious approach is to generate one of the parametric families.

Comment: As I understand it, the scoring is now exclusively based on number of bricks found, so the code-golf tag is inappropriate. I'll go ahead and replace it with a code-challenge tag (it seems more appropriate than the fastest-code tag.

Comment: Finally. I'm glad they let this post out of jail.

Comment: At present the only output is a number of bricks "calculated". What does it mean to "calculate" a brick?

Comment: Has anyone actually attempted this challenge? I'm wonder what kind of numbers you guys are getting. I've got a program that finds like, 4 or 5 bricks in 2 minutes. It is incredibly sub-optimal, but still I was thinking Euler bricks would be more common..

Comment: @stokastic That seems much slower than I expected...

Comment: @BetaDecay I feel the same. With optimizations I feel like I could speed it up as much as 10x, but even then it will only be around 20-30 bricks per minute. I'm curious to see the algorithms other people use.

Comment: @stokastic, 29 million in 4.5 seconds, but using 1.5GB of memory. I only have 4GB of physical RAM on this machine, so that's the limiting factor for me. But at the moment I'm using the memory as write-once-read-once, and by turning it into a circular buffer I should be able to improve. Failing that there's a tradeoff which uses much less memory but much more CPU.

Comment: Just an outsider's perspective here, all of the comments make me unsure of whether this is currently a good question or not. No matter how much I *think* it's a cool idea. Maybe hash it out in chat next time.

Comment: It’s a little bit confusing that the picture also shows the space diagonal, which is never mentioned again.

Comment: The scoreboard looks a very imbalanced. From hundreds of millions of bricks per minute down to 0.5 brick per minute. haha

Comment: Donald Trump's favourite question on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### C using Saunderson's parameterisation and Berggren's tree

In 1740, Saunderson found the parameterisation that if `(a, b, c)` is a Pythagorean triple (i.e. `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`) then `(a(2b-c)(2b+c), b(2a-c)(2a+c), 4abc)` is a *rational cuboid* (this was before Euler studied them) with diagonals `(c^3, a(5b^2+a^2), b(5a^2+b^2))`. This doesn't generate all Euler bricks. Note that if the brick is primitive iff the Pythagorean triple is primitive.

If `(x, y, z)` is an Euler brick then so is `(xy, xz, yz)`. Applying this once to a Saunderson brick creates a new brick which isn't Saunderson and which can be made primitive with division by `ab`. Applying the same transformation a second time gives the non-primitive `xyz(x, y, z)`.

In 1934, Berggren discovered that the primitive Pythagorean triples form a ternary tree rooted at `(3, 4, 5)` which can be generated by a simple matrix multiplication and which contains each triple precisely once.

This implementation generates primitive Pythagorean triples and stores them in a stack, limiting the memory usage to 1.5GB. An earlier version used a circular buffer, but the stack gives much better results. This is probably a combination of fewer values being discarded and better cache locality.

Thanks to [Steve Verrill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/steveverrill) for pointing out some bugs and for suggesting the use of a stack instead of a circular buffer. I've also followed him in removing the conjugate bricks for speed: previously the search space (minus the discarded branches) was exhausted within the two minutes, and there was value in spending time to get a few conjugates. But the new version can easily run for 5 minutes (as I discovered in the process of learning the value of the `volatile` keyword!), and most of the conjugates overflow, so on average the tests are wasted time.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

// Stack size. This is 1.5GB of memory. 
#define N 33554432

typedef unsigned __int128 scalar;

typedef struct {
    scalar a, b, c;
} triple;

// Stack operations
#define take(st) st[--stp];
#define offer(A,B,C) if (stp < N) { st[stp].a=(A); st[stp].b=(B); st[stp].c=(C); stp++; }

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {
    stop = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Register interrupt handler
    stop = 0;
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0) return 1;

    // L = 10^30
    const scalar L = ((scalar)0xc9f2c9cd0UL << 64) + 0x4674edea40000000UL;
    const scalar T = (scalar)1 << 64;   // used in an anti-overflow test

    // To avoid the optimiser removing the calculation of the bricks.
    int writeToStdOut = argc > 1;

    triple *st = (triple *)malloc(N * sizeof(triple));
    if (!st) return 2;

    uint32_t stp = 1; // Index of first empty space in stack
    st[0].a = 3; st[0].b = 4; st[0].c = 5;
    uint64_t count = 0;

    while (stp > 0) {
        if (stop) break;
        triple t = take(st);

        // Extend queue of Pythagorean triples
        offer(t.a + ((t.c - t.b) << 1), ((t.a + t.c) << 1) - t.b, ((t.a - t.b + t.c) << 1) + t.c)
        offer(t.a + ((t.c + t.b) << 1), ((t.a + t.c) << 1) + t.b, ((t.a + t.b + t.c) << 1) + t.c)
        offer(-t.a + ((t.c + t.b) << 1), ((-t.a + t.c) << 1) + t.b, ((-t.a + t.b + t.c) << 1) + t.c)

        // Saunderson brick
        scalar x = t.b * ( ((t.a << 1) >= t.c) ? ((t.a << 1) - t.c) : (t.c - (t.a << 1)) ) * ((t.a << 1) + t.c);
        scalar y = t.a * ((t.b << 1) - t.c) * ((t.b << 1) + t.c);
        scalar z = t.a * t.b * t.c << 2;
        scalar u = t.c * t.c * t.c;
        scalar v = t.b * (t.b * t.b + 5 * t.a * t.a);
        scalar w = t.a * (t.a * t.a + 5 * t.b * t.b);
        count++;
        if (writeToStdOut) {
            printf("Sides: 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(x >> 64), (uint64_t)x);
            printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(y >> 64), (uint64_t)y);
            printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(z >> 64), (uint64_t)z);
            printf("; diags 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(u >> 64), (uint64_t)u);
            printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(v >> 64), (uint64_t)v);
            printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64"\n", (uint64_t)(w >> 64), (uint64_t)w);
        }
    }

    printf("%ld\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with `gcc -O3 euler_brick.c -o euler_brick` and handles `SIGINT` (Ctrl-C).  On my computer the earlier circular buffer version ran out of usably small Pythagorean triples after 85 seconds having found `843035517` (0.843 thousand million) Euler bricks. The new version runs to the two minutes (tested with `timeout -sINT 2m ./euler_brick`) and finds about 9.1 thousand million bricks. Exact numbers vary from run to run; the highest I've observed is `9113459216`.

Note that this is single-threaded code. The process is embarrassingly parallel - just start each thread going down a different branch of the tree - and so the limitation to scaling it to multicore would be the shared memory bus.

Comment: Man you did your research. I had a 'similar' approach, but it was about 8 orders of magnitude more naive. I was using a similar process to generate co-prime integers which can be used to generate pythagorean triples, and then comparing linear combinations of the triples to find cuboids. I guess I didn't hit google hard enough ;)

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using because I'm getting a load of errors when I try to compile your code?

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/eZ3YFQXx) is what I'm getting.

Comment: @BetaDecay, GCC 4.6, 64-bit Linux. There seem to be two important differences between my environment and yours: firstly, your target apparently doesn't support [__int128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) (are you using a 32-bit OS?); secondly, you don't apparently have a POSIX-compliant `signal.h`.

Comment: I'm on 64-bit Windows 7. I'll try it on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.02

Comment: This is amazing. A couple of comments: 1.Your non-Saunderson brick isn't primitive, it's divisible by `ab`. 2.With recursion you can avoid the memory issue (though the brick sizes would be all over the place. Considering both of these points would increase the number of (sufficiently small) bricks found. I'm still debating whether to do my own program.

Comment: The first is an excellent point: I shall correct the program later. The second is an interesting one, but I wonder whether a tail recursion would be better because the stack could still get quite large.

Comment: I tried recursion and I do need to limit the stack size, see my answer. However I don't think I'm losing many bricks that way. I noticed another thing in your code: I'm not sure how `if (x < 0) x = -x;` works with an unsigned variable. I found I had to check the sign of both `x` and `y`, but I made the tree a different way.

Comment: I managed to get it working on my Ubuntu machine (Linux FTW!) and the number of bricks calculated in 2 minutes was `11463359371`.

Comment: Peter, as I was getting 1.6E9 bricks of side <10^30 with my program running to completion and stack limitation was having little effect, I was surprised you got so many more. I looked at your code and I can't see a check for length, so I put one in (only on z which is the longest side) and rearranged the code slightly to make the check efficient. I get  1691332623 bricks at completion, which is slightly more than I found with my stack limited to 5000. I also added a "stack full" warning to your massive stack. As it was not displayed I assume that's all saunderson bricks of side < 10^30.

Comment: Without the length check I suspect that your program was reaching bricks of 2^128 in size and overflowing. See my edits at http://pastebin.com/4Z2YACzN . I also added a getchar() after the brick dimension display to slow it down. That shows a minor issue (that I haven't fixed):  It seems that there is underflow on y fairly early on, which means that the program is calculating some negative y's. Anyway, you deserve the win because you found the maths, and went to the effort of writing a custom stack, so I very much appreciate the bonus.

Answer (score 5):

## C using Saunderson's parameterisation and a different tree generation method.

This is heavily influenced by Peter Taylor's answer, and by the following page: https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0021. For consistency, my variable naming convention largely follows Peter's.

Instead of using a buffer, I use recursion to generate the three children of each node of the tree. The tree I generate is equivalent to Berggren's tree, but I use a two-parameter method (mainly for interest and variation.) The parameters `p` and `q` for all integers generate a pythagorean triple `a=p^2-q^2, b=2pq, c=p^2+q^2`. If we want to limit this to primitive triples only, we start with the vector (2,1) and multiply by the 2x2 matrices below. This is equivalent to Berggren's / Barning's method, in which we start with the vector (3,4,5) and multiply by the 3x3 matrices below. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples .

```
Barning's matrices                       2x2 matrices
1 -2  2      1  2  2     -1  2  2        2 -1    2  1    1  2
2 -1  2      2  1  2     -2  1  2        1  0    1  0    0  1
2 -2  3      2  2  3     -2  2  3
```

It can be seen from Barning's matrices that the hypotenuse `c` of the second child of each node will be between 3 and 7 times larger than that of its parent (more advanced treatment would narrow this range.) the growth rates of the other branches are rather slower.

In practice it was necessary to limit the depth of recursion in order to avoid stack overflow (segmentation fault.) However, it seems likely that only a few bricks were lost. Peter's program runs on my machine in about 6 minutes and generates `843035517` Euler bricks. My program takes just over twice as long and generates `1688135295` bricks with recursion depth limited to `5000`, or `1671621046` bricks with depth limited to `1000`. Therefore the rate of generation is about the same. With depth limited to `40`, `1134616080` bricks are generated, of which 1131433861 are Saunderson and only 3182219 are conjugate. And the program runs about twice as fast with the code for generating conjugate bricks commented out!

Instead of generating the conjugate brick of `(x,y,z)` as `(yz,xz,xy)` I generate a conjugate brick `ab` times smaller. To do this intermediate values `x',y',u',v'` are stored during the calculation of `x,y,z,u,v,w`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int writeStdOut,count=0;

typedef __int128 scalar;

scalar L=(scalar)1000000*1000000*1000000*1000000*1000000,T=(scalar)1<<124;

f(scalar p, scalar q, int depth){
  scalar p2,q2,
         a,b,c,a2,b2,c2,
         uprime,vprime,u,v,w,
         xprime,yprime,x,y,z;

  p2=p*p;q2=q*q;
  a=p2-q2;b=p*q<<1;c=p2+q2;  

  z=a*b*c<<2;
  if(z<L){
    a2=a*a;b2=b*b;c2=c*c;

    xprime=(b2<<2)-c2;yprime=(a2<<2)-c2;
    if(xprime<0)xprime=-xprime;if(yprime<0)yprime=-yprime;
    x=a*xprime;y=b*yprime;
  
    uprime=b2*5+a2;vprime=a2*5+b2;
    u=a*uprime;v=b*vprime; w=c2*c;
  
    count++;
    if (writeStdOut) {
      printf("Sides: 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(x >> 64), (uint64_t)x);
      printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(y >> 64), (uint64_t)y);
      printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(z >> 64), (uint64_t)z);
      printf("; diags 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(u >> 64), (uint64_t)u);
      printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(v >> 64), (uint64_t)v);
      printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64"\n", (uint64_t)(w >> 64), (uint64_t)w);
    }
    if(T/a/c>xprime && T/b/c>yprime){
      x=a*c*xprime<<2;y=b*c*yprime<<2; if(x<0 | y<0)puts("overflow"); 
      if(x<L && y<L){
      
        z=xprime*yprime;
        u=uprime*yprime;v=vprime*xprime;w=c2*c2<<2;
        count++; 
        if (writeStdOut) {
          printf("SIDES: 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(x >> 64), (uint64_t)x);
          printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(y >> 64), (uint64_t)y);
          printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(z >> 64), (uint64_t)z);
          printf("; diags 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(u >> 64), (uint64_t)u);
          printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64, (uint64_t)(v >> 64), (uint64_t)v);
          printf(", 0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64"\n", (uint64_t)(w >> 64), (uint64_t)w);
        }

      }
    }
    if(depth<40){f((p<<1)-q,p,depth+1);f((p<<1)+q,p,depth+1);f(p+(q<<1),q,depth+1);}
  }
}

main(int argc, char **argv){
  writeStdOut=argc>1;
  f(2,1,0);
  printf(" %d bricks",count);
}
```

Comment: Your answer deserves to get you at least as much rep as mine got me. Thanks for pointing out the bugs and for suggesting a massive improvement.

Comment: I had to modify your code to include a signal interrupt, but after 2 minutes your code calculated `680262303` bricks.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus @PeterTaylor! I had started thinking about some rather more naive ideas when I saw your answer. All I did was copy your maths. I've finally got round to running your code today. I will comment soon.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - Brute forcing it

### Edit: This produces a measly 0.5 bricks per minute...

To get the ball rolling again, I decided to write a simple entry. As always with brute force methods, it's extremely slow.

```
def mult(x,y):
    c=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
      if y[i]%x[i]==0:c+=1
    if c==3:return True
    return False

pyth=lambda x,y:True if (x**2+y**2)**0.5==int((x**2+y**2)**0.5) else False
prev=[]
ymax=245
zmax=269
try:
    for x in range(44,10**30):
        for y in range(117,ymax):
            ymax+=1
            for z in range(240,zmax):
                zmax+=1
                curr=[x,y,z]
                eq=0
                ml=0
                for i in range(3):
                    for j in range(3):
                        if i!=j:
                            if curr[i]==curr[j]:
                                eq+=1
                for k in prev:
                    if mult(curr, k):
                        ml+=1
                if eq==0 and ml==0:
                    f=pyth(curr[0],curr[1])
                    s=pyth(curr[0],curr[2])
                    b=pyth(curr[1],curr[2])
                    if f and s and b:
                        prev.append(curr)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n\n'+str(len(prev)))
```